# CMYK colours wrong on export in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, export, cmyk

I am making a flyer on Illustrator. It has a grey background `0,0,0,30` is the CMYK value. When I export to any format or even in RGB the grey seems to have a red hue to it.

How do i get a realistic transfer of the colours im working in when exporting?

Comment: That's unusual, does it also seem red when you print it? It'd be great if you could show a sample

Comment: I think it's because your name is, Red.

Comment: it prints out fine, i was just wanting a jpeg of it with an accurate colour representaion

Comment: What are the colors which *are not* the background? Are they heavy on the warm side of the color wheel?

Comment: It appears to be missing some cyan, ive tried to manually up the cyan levels, but it doesnt work. I've found a workaround for the problem....converting to pdf, and then to jpg

Comment: It is relative... "seems to have a red hue". Read the values in photoshop or see the channels. It it only "seems" and the numbers are correct, then it could be a problem with the monitor or an optical ilusion. Inclusive your eyes can become uncalibrated. Do the exercise explained here: http://www.otake.com.mx/Apuntes/ColorCalibration/ColorCalibration.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under 'File' check that the document mode is set to CMYK. Instead of 'Export' go to 'Save a Copy' and choose 'Adobe PDF'. In the options dialogue box click on 'Standard' and select a suitable print standard such as PDF/X-1a:2001

I just did an 'Export' as JPG from Illustrator and checked it in Photoshop with the 'Info' tool and the colour shows as 0, 0, 0, 30. It looks grey on the screen, too.

I cannot replicate the problem so suggest you check that the colour mode is CMYK not RGB (under 'File'  'Document Color Mode') and also check you are using CMYK in the colour palette and/or swatches.

Comment: That works great...but is there any way to export to a jpeg with an accurate representation of the colour rather than a pdf?

Comment: As a hack you could change the  pdf to a jpeg...

Comment: Did you also confirm that your `Document Color Mode` is CMYK as @Bob suggested?

Comment: yes its in cmyk

yeah jenna thats what ive ende dup doing

Answer (score 0):

for what is is worth, all this time later, you can sucessfully export a JPG with the correct colours if you use the **Export > Save for Web (Legacy)** dialog.  don't know what the new dialog does that breaks it so horribly, but there you go.  just use the old stuff.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is an issue with *CMYK-JPGs*. They often show wierd results when viewed, but the files actually have the right values in their four color channels. Not a lot of apps can handle their display properly. If you use the "Save for Web" dialogue in Illustrator to export JPGs you will always generate a *RGB-JPG* which will look much better in most apps, especially web browsers.

*CMYK-JPGs* are only useful if you want to print them in a 4-c process. For screen use I'd recommend using *RGB-JPGs*.

Answer (score -1):

Same thing happened to me and I have checked that document is set cmyk. In pdf it comes out correct.